# mongoose.connect(), first argument should be String, received undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I am trying to set the test database for the testing purpose, but its not working.

I am trying to connect to MongoDB using mongoose, but finding problem in the connection error shows:

```
throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
    ^
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()`is a string.
    at new MongooseError (/media/abhigyan/ABHI/programming/node js/Practice/On my Own/Todo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/mongooseError.js:11:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/media/abhigyan/ABHI/programming/node js/Practice/On my Own/Todo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:424:11)
    at Mongoose.connect (/media/abhigyan/ABHI/programming/node js/Practice/On my Own/Todo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:230:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/abhigyan/ABHI/programming/node js/Practice/On my Own/Todo/server/db/mongoose.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/abhigyan/ABHI/programming/node js/Practice/On my Own/Todo/server/models/Todo.js:1:82)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/abhigyan/ABHI/programming/node js/Practice/On my Own/Todo/server/tests/server.test.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /media/abhigyan/ABHI/programming/node js/Practice/On my Own/Todo/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:250:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/media/abhigyan/ABHI/programming/node js/Practice/On my Own/Todo/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:247:14)
    at Mocha.run (/media/abhigyan/ABHI/programming/node js/Practice/On my Own/Todo/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:576:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/abhigyan/ABHI/programming/node js/Practice/On my Own/Todo/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:637:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I am passing a valid String, but Its not working!

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, err => {
    if(err) 
        console.log(err);
    } 
);



module.exports = {
    mongoose
};
```

Here is the Script to run mocha:

```
export NODE_ENV='test' && mocha server/**/*.test.js
```

Here is the configuration code:

```
const config = require('./config.json');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV.toString() || 'development';

if(env === 'test' || env === 'development') {
    const envConfig = config[env];
    Object.keys(envConfig).forEach(key => {
        process.env[key] = envConfig[key];
    });
};

console.log(env);
```

Here is the config.json file:

```
{
    "test": {
        "PORT": 3000,
        "MONGODB_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoTest"
    },
    "development": {
        "PORT": 3000,
        "MONGODB_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/Todo"
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think you miss importing `env` file.

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'ENV_FILENAME' });
```

Answer (score 18):

To read from .env file you have to install dotenv ( npm i dotenv / yarn add dotenv)
and then just add this on top of your file.

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();
```

Answer (score 9):

I was also facing same problem after add code  **`{ useNewUrlParser: true }`**  in mongoose.connect() method.  Problem resolved.

```
mongoose.connect(config.DB,{ useNewUrlParser: true }));
```

Answer (score 7):

In the server directory,

1. ```
   npm install dotenv
   ```
2. In your server.js:
   If you use "type":"module" in your package.json file then,

   ```
   import dotenv from 'dotenv';
   import mongoose from 'mongoose'; 
   dotenv.config();
   ```

   or,

   ```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose')
   require('dotenv').config()
   ```
3. Add a .env file in the server directory,

   ```
   PORT=5000
   MONGO_URL= yourURL
   ```
4. In the server.js,

   ```
   const url = process.env.MONGO_URL
   mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
   .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server up and running!")
   .catch((error) => console.log(error.message) 
   mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)
   ```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem.
1. I saved my ATLAS_URI ID to a file called .env
2. My .env file was in the **wrong directory**, that's how the problem cause
3. Solution: I used "ls -a" command to make sure my .env file is in the same location as my server

Answer (score 6):

**i have encountered the same error, this thread didn't help... here's my solution it was simple! im using express, mongo, mongoose, and dotENV**

**file 1 === db.js**

```
 import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connectDB =  async ()=>{

    try{
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{
            //must add in order to not get any error masseges:
            useUnifiedTopology:true,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true
        })
        console.log(`mongo database is connected!!! ${conn.connection.host} `)
    }catch(error){
        console.error(`Error: ${error} `)
        process.exit(1) //passing 1 - will exit the proccess with error
    }

}

export default connectDB
```

**file 2= server.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import connectDB from './config/db.js' // DB connection
import products from './data/products.js'

dotenv.config()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV

const app = express()

connectDB() //this function connects us to the DB!!!
. . . more code…
```

*> solution: the connectDB() expression must come after the dotenv.config() expression.
and that's it ! :)*

Comment: Man! You just did it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since error message returned UNDEFINED uri parameter, `.toString()`  will NOT work.
You can use the `String()` function: `String(your connection parameter)`.
Also, in `if(env === 'test' || env === 'development')`  try not to use (===), it is a strict equality.

Instead try `if(env == 'test' || env == 'development')`. This is a loose equality.  It doesn't care about the type match and will convert second operand's type to first one's type.

Answer (score 3):

try using this method worked for me.

```
mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URL}`, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, ()=>{
    console.log("mongodb is connected")
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

there is a very small mistake Your .env file should exist in your project directory. maybe your .env file is placed in a different folder. check your  .env file location

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below steps

Step 1 - Install dotenv package

```
# with npm
npm install dotenv

# with Yarn
yarn add dotenv
```

Step 2 - Create a new env file e.g config.env

[image]

Step 3 - Write the below code in the config.env file

```
DATABASE = MONGO_URL
PORT = port_number
```

Step 4 - Write the below code in your main server file (in my case it is index.js)

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");  //require dotenv package
dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" }); //import config.env file

const DB = process.env.DATABASE;  
const Port = process.env.PORT;

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    usenewurlparser: true,
    useunifiedtopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected ");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(`can not connect to database, ${error}`);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved my problem. Happy Coding!

```
// Connect to MongoDB
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://yourusername:yourpassword@ds121825.mlab.com:11025/yourmongodb', {useNewUrlParser: true});
    mongoose.connection.once('open', function(){
      console.log('Conection has been made!');
    }).on('error', function(error){
        console.log('Error is: ', error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but then I realized that I saved the .env file as .env.txt which caused the issue. I deleted the file and created another file without .txt at the end and everything worked find.

I hope this helps.

Dhiya Aljaradi

Answer (score 1):

```
const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true
    })
```

Always put `useNewUrlParser:true` before putting the `useUnifiedTopology:true`, and then the rest.

Answer (score 1):

i have taken this error message, you have to declare .env file after installing dotenv package. if you declare file before installing package , variable will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, fixed by adding this code snippet.

```
mongoose.connect(config.DB,{ useMongoClient:true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the .env file with the constants that you are using defined.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, for me it was because I was trying to use environment variables in `globalSetup` which had the file for initiating db connection.. `mongoose.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__`

[image]

Apparently, environment variables are not initialised yet in `globalSetup` so I had to move the code somewhere else, either to `setupFilesAfterEnv` or by using [Async Test Environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
const db = process.env.MONGO || 'test'    
    
mongoose.connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology:true,
      useCreateIndex: true
    }).then(()=>{
      console.log("conected to mongodb");
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("mongo error",error);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the env

```
const db = process.env.MONGO || 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you've forgotten to import/require dotenv, then you can run dotenv before running your app using **--require dotenv/config**

```
node --require dotenv/config index.js // regular node command

// nodemon to restart application whenever a file gets changed
nodemon --require dotenv/config index.js

// integrate with babel-node if you're using latest JS features like import/export
nodemon --require dotenv/config index.js --exec babel-node
```

No need to require dotenv and call config function within codebase. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing wrong was I created js file to store the key:

```
module.export = {
MONGOURI : "Your Key"
}
```

and from my app.js I was fetching the key with different keyname like

```
const {MongoUri} = require('./keys')
```

after changing MongoUri to MONGOURI , it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If we don't want to define the path of the .env file like this,

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'ENV_FILENAME' });
```

we can place .env file in the same place as our main file, which was App.js in my case. So we could directly write

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue and here is my fix:
the process.env.MONGODB_URL should be in a string.
Check it out

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('process.env.MONGODB_URI', err => {
    if(err) 
        console.log(err);
    } 
);



module.exports = {
    mongoose
};
```

Answer (score 0):

my `.env` file was named `.dotenv` by mistake.
after changing it to `.env` everything worked

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue, Make sure that you have the .env in "/" (next to your package.json file).if do not want to require and load dotenv in your application code or still have an issue run your server through:

`node -r dotenv/config your_script.js`.

---

otherwise, if your file containing environment variables is located elsewhere, you have to use path module:

common js: `require('dotenv').config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })`

ES:`dotenv.config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })`

Answer (score 0):

after using
require("dotenv").config();  or import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config(); put your .env file in the same folder as server file

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the ".env" file in your folder has the exact name, else it won't work.
If you have named the ".env" file something else then please change it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. I solved it easily.

- Step 1:  npm install dotenv
- Step 2: require('dotenv').config()
- Step 3: Create a .env file
- Step 4: Push Into this code dot env (.env) file DB_USER = ******** and DB_PASS = ********
- Step 5:

const dbURL = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@techbd71.5ewxj.mongodb.net/`enter
table name here`?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

```
mongoose.connect(dbURL, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then(()=>console.log('DB Ok'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are getting the same error, Even after configuring dotenv** and setting everything step by step, then you have to restart your MongoDB and server and wait for some time.
**Look at the images, I have done nothing, just restarted MongoDB, and the server**

sometimes it's a **mongo server** issue
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck with same problem so I fixed it like this..

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.h9zpqsi.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority',{
useNewUrlParser:true,})

// Using **MONGO_URI** instead of using **process.env.MONGO_URI**

Answer (score 0):

I was deploying my MERN stack web application to Heroku so I came through this error .So I was entering the Mongo_DB_URL in this way in Heroku Config Vars.

```
"mongodb+srv://aaronhakso:eyPy7Zr6WznMs82l@chatbot-db.faegc3w.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

But when I removed these double quotes the error was resolved.I wrote the string in the following way to remove the error

```
mongodb+srv://aaronhakso:eyPy7Zr6WznMs82l@chatbot-db.faegc3w.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Also, make sure to call dotenv at the top of the code.
The following code gives you the above error as you mentioned above  
// Connecting to DataBase    
        connectDB();    
        const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();    
The Correct Way  
        const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();    
        // Connecting to DataBase    
        connectDB();
```

Answer (score -2):

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

Comment: Please write in English :-)