# What is MONGO_URL and what should it be set to?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I downloaded some code from GitHub to run it locally on my machine and play around with it. This is the first time downloading or working with MongoDB. I followed the instructions to download MongoDB from [this website](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). Then I made sure MongoDB is started using the `sudo service mongod start` command.

Once it's started, I run the project I downloaded from GitHub using `node application.js` command. I get an error:

```
throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

From what I see, the code I downloaded has this connection statement:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("connection error:", err);
    } else {
        console.log("MongoDB connection successful");
    }
});
```

I can't seem to find `MONGO_URL`. Doing a bit of googling I see a lot of people mentioning meteor however I'm not using that. From what I've gathered, this is the path MongoDB uses to connect to the local DB that's running on my machine. However this is not set anywhere in the project or during installation.

Is my understanding correct? Sounds like I need to define a new environment variable on my Linux machine. What should this variable be set to? I plan on only running this project on my machine for learning purposes.

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: `mongodb://localhost:27017`

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately but it did give me a meaningful error about the db name so I had to add `/<db name>` at the end of that statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mongoose.connection()` takes [3 values](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/2cd939e4cfc42329b046f1ef197f8f8bb0472981/lib/connection.js#L459)

```
Connection.prototype.openUri = function(uri, options, callback) {
    …
};
```

> throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
>   MongooseError: **The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"**. Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string

As suggested by your error message, the `uri` you’re passing turns out to be an `undefined`. This happens if you don't a value for it.

Can you please log the value of `process.env.MONGO_URL` and see the value.

```
console.log(‘Connection url => ’, process.env.MONGO_URL);
```

Since you’ve install the mongo db, it will, by default run in `mongodb://localhost:27017` url.

Instead of hard coding the connection url, you can consider passing such values as environment values

If you’ve just one environment value, you can pass it along with the installation

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017 node index.js
```

If you’ve more than 2-3 environment variable per app or multiple apps all using environment variable, it can quickly pollute your environment with too many values. You can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for configuring them using `.env` file

Install [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Create a `.env` file at the root of the project and [ignore it in `.gitignore`](https://github.com/sridharrajs/nodejs-api-boilerplate/blob/master/.gitignore#L6)

**.env**

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017
```

In your code,

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL); //you can access it straight way
```

We are doing this to [**stricly separate config from code**](https://12factor.net/config), which will help us avoid checking in sensitive details to GitHub

You can take a look at [a sample project](https://github.com/sridharrajs/nodejs-api-boilerplate#development) where I've [configured](https://github.com/sridharrajs/nodejs-api-boilerplate/blob/master/server.js#L9L18) the above details.

Comment: I hard coded the path in the function as mentioned in the above. You mentioned that by default it should run if mongodb is installed. As suspected, the console log of `process.env.MONGO_URL` is undefined. Where and when should this be defined? because I installed mongodb using the steps mention in my original post.

Comment: if you use `MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017 node index.js`, `process.env.MONGO_URL` will be set to `mongodb://localhost:27017`. This because mongodb runs at port 27017 in localhost

Comment: Understood. Where would I set this? Would I have to add it to my Linux environment variables?

Comment: @MB41 added the details of where and how with one of my sample projects :)

Answer (score 1):

If your database is on the local machine, then you need to do,

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

If connecting fails on your machine, try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: Thank you. But are these environment variable supposed to be set when downloading MongoDB? Because I see same issue with `process.env.SESSION_SECRET`.

Comment: you've to set your own environment variables

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62615775/1235675), I was using [jest-mongodb](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mongodb) and my problem was trying to use environment variables in `globalSetup` when they are not initialised yet..