# I'm trying to initialize a database connection but I get a The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, server

The error on terminal

:\Users\HOPE\Tutorial_API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694
throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
^

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\HOPE\Tutorial_API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694:11)
at C:\Users\HOPE\Tutorial_API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:380:10
at C:\Users\HOPE\Tutorial_API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
at new Promise ()
at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\HOPE\Tutorial_API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\HOPE\Tutorial_API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1225:10)
at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\HOPE\Tutorial_API\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:379:20)
at connectDatabase (C:\Users\HOPE\Tutorial_API\config\db.js:5:14)
at Object. (C:\Users\HOPE\Tutorial_API\server.js:7:23)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)

my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const health = require('./routes/healthChecker.routes');
const app = express();

require('./config/db')();

app.use(express.json());

app.use('/health', health)


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

my database file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDatabase = () => {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_LOCAL_URI, {
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        })
        .then((con) => {
            console.log(`MongoDB Database connected to host ${con.connection.host}`);
        });
}

module.exports = connectDatabase;
```

my default.json file

```
{
    "values": {
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
        "DB_LOCAL_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
    }
}
```

what might be the issue?

Comment: Checkout this resource if it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770772/mongoose-connect-first-argument-should-be-string-received-undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing up **two** ways to include environment variables.

**The first way is the one you've chosen**: to use a `default.json` file which uses the `config` npm package

`npm i config`

```js
const config = require('config');
```

you can then use parameters from your `default.json` file this way:

```js
config.get('values.DB_LOCAL_URI');
```

ie.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDatabase = () => {
    mongoose.connect(config.get('values.DB_LOCAL_URI'), {
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        })
        .then((con) => {
            console.log(`MongoDB Database connected to host ${con.connection.host}`);
        });
}

module.exports = connectDatabase;
```

**The second way** is to use a `.env` file which lives in your node file's directory as looks like this:

```
URL = "http://localhost:3000/"
DB_LOCAL_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
```

Install `dotenv` package:

`npm i dotenv`

You access your `.env` file with a require statement in your `server.js` file (which references your database file):

server.js

```js
require('dotenv').config();
```

and then by using this pattern:

```js
process.env.DB_LOCAL_URI
```

like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDatabase = () => {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_LOCAL_URI), {
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        })
        .then((con) => {
            console.log(`MongoDB Database connected to host ${con.connection.host}`);
        });
}

module.exports = connectDatabase;
```

In summary, you've used the pattern (`process.env.MYVARIABLE`) of the second method, whereas you're trying to access the environmental/settings file (`default.json`) using the first method.

Answer (score 1):

**Connection error: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.**

The issue can be resolved by utilizing the `dotenv` package to manage environment variables in your project. Here's how I managed to fix the error:

**Step 1: Install `dotenv`**

First, install the `dotenv` package by running the following command in your project directory:

```
npm install dotenv
```

**Step 2: Configure Your `.env` File**

Create a `.env` file in the root directory of your project and add your MongoDB connection string as an environment variable:

```
MONGODB_URI="mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.lghcp.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

**Step 3: Modify db.js/server.js**

In your db.js file, require and configure `dotenv` at the beginning of the file:

```
require('dotenv').config(); // Load environment variables from .env file

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to the database');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Connection error:', err.message);
    });
```

By requiring and configuring `dotenv` in your db.js/server file, the environment variables from your `.env` file will be available, including the `MONGODB_URI` value.

Answer (score 1):

**Connection error: MongoParseError: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"**

Someone might also encounter the issue above and I've found a solution that might help you resolve this issue. It's related to the format of the `MONGODB_URI` in your `.env` file. Here's what you can do:

**Step 1: Review Your `.env` File**

Check your .env file where you store your MongoDB connection string. Make sure the format starts with either "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://". You might be encountering this error if the scheme is incorrect.

**Step 2: Remove Semicolon from `MONGODB_URI`**

It appears that a common issue causing this error is having a semicolon (;) at the end of the `MONGODB_URI` in the `.env` file. Make sure your `MONGODB_URI` does not end with a semicolon.

For example, ensure your `.env` file looks like this (without the semicolon at the end):

```
MONGODB_URI="mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.lghcp.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

**Step 3: Restart Your Application**

After making the changes in your `.env file`, save the file and restart your Node.js application to ensure the updated configuration is loaded.