# Problem trying to connect to mongoDB.MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i'm trying to learn MERN stack i got a problm trying to connect to mongodb
tried reinstalling dotenv and also tried puting database URI directly in the db file
here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
const {errorHandler} = require('./middleware/errorMiddleware');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/api/goals', require('./routes/goalRoutes')) ;
app.use(errorHandler)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`cserver started on port ${port}`));
```

here is the db file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)

    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

and the .env

```
NODE_ENV = developement
PORT = 8000
MONGO_URI = mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&ssl=false
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is your .env file and app.js file present at the root of project directory? And also check if other environment variables are loaded inside app.js by console logging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongoose.connect(), first argument should be String, received undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770772/mongoose-connect-first-argument-should-be-string-received-undefined)

Comment: i've already seen this post and tried every one of  the solutions and i still get the same error, and yes the .env file and app.js file are at the root

Comment: That's really weird, ca you tell your node version?

Comment: my node version is 16.16